# Django+gunicorn service mistake?

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

I tried to deploy django on my server via this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-debian-8)
 I have a problem with configurating gunicorn.service.
When I do

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

I get

```
gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-05-13 11:47:49 MSK; 29s ago
 Main PID: 56584 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
May 13 11:47:49 debian systemd[1]: Starting gunicorn daemon...
May 13 11:47:49 debian systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
May 13 11:47:49 debian systemd[56584]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/bl...ry
May 13 11:47:49 debian systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: main process exited, c...EC
May 13 11:47:49 debian systemd[1]: Unit gunicorn.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

My structure of the project

```
splitpoint@debian:/opt/blog$ tree
.
├── myproject
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── myproject
│   │   ├── gunicorn.config.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── static
│       └── admin
│           ├── css
│           etc
└── venv
    ├── bin
    │   ├── activate
        etc
```

My gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=splitpoint
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/opt/blog/
ExecStart=/opt/blog/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/opt/blog/myproje$


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How can I fix gunicorn to activate(running) it?

Comment: Try running `gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/opt/blog/myproje...` from the shell, but append `--preload` at the end. If it's an issue of a missing package, code error, etc - you'll be able to see it with that.

Comment: I try to start that from directory where my project is placed. And I got splitpoint@debian:/opt/blog$ gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/myproject --preload
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: No application module specified.

Comment: Your command is missing a chunk, it should look like: `gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/opt/blog/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application --preload`